# Python 3 Collecting Tables together

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I have multiple tables that all look the same. They are of the format

|TIME|SF|COL3|COL4|COL5|

All the data in the tables are floats, and separated just by whitespace. All tables have identical TIME columns, and the values of COL3, COL4 and COL5 are not useful. What I would like to do, is create a new file with the data

|TIME|SF_1|SF_2|SF_3|...|SF_N|

So I need the code to work for N number of tables (all of identical format).

So far I have done:

```
files = (np.loadtxt('files.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True))
i=0
while i<len(files):
    if i == 0:
        readfile = np.loadtxt(files[i], dtype=str, unpack=True, usecols=range(0,3))
        time=readfile[0]
        print(time)
        globals()["SF_"+str(i)]=readfile[1]
    else:
        readfile = np.loadtxt(files[i], dtype=str, unpack=False, usecols=1)
        globals()["SF_"+str(i)] = readfile
```

(where `files.txt` is a list of all the table names).

So this has given me the list TIME, and then variables SF_1, SF_2, SF_3 etc, although it does so in an inelegant way. Now however I can't figure out how to output this into a datafile as separate columns rather than rows. Any advice would be appreciated, including how to improve my previous code as I am very aware its unadvised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem with the following code

```
files = np.loadtxt('files.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)
i=0
while i<len(files):
    if i==0:
        readfile = np.loadtxt(files[i], dtype=float, unpack=True, usecols=range(0,3))
        time = readfile[0] #although for only the first file it also extracts time
        SF = readfile[1]
        out_table = np.vstack((time, SF))
    else:
        readfile = np.loadtxt(files[i], dtype=float, unpack=False, usecols=1)
        SF = np.array(readfile)
        out_table = np.vstack((out_table, SF))
    i+=1
out_table = out_table.T

#Creates the Header line of column names for easy importing into TOPCAT
n=1
header = '#BJD '
while n < len(out_table[0]):
    header = header + 'SF_'+str(n)+' '
    n += 1
output.write(header+"MEDSF\n")

#Prints each row into the output file line by line
j=0
while j<len(out_table):
    output.write(" ".join(map(str, out_table[j]))+" "+str(np.median(out_table[j]))+"\n")
    j+=1

output.close()
```